# Can we increase temperature of a gas by oscillating its pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics

Q: **Is temperature directly proportional to rate of ***fluctuation*** of pressure?**

--->**What  I mean by Oscillation/Fluctuation of Pressure**

From oscillation of pressure I mean constantly increasing and decreasing the pressure by a fixed amount.
For example imagine a room with a pressure of 50 pascal, if we first increase its pressure to 55 and then decrease the pressure to 45 that would be oscillating the pressure by 5 units back and forth

Suppose we do not add more molecules and our cube container is changing the shape. There are no sound-like longitudinal waves produced and everywhere pressure changes at the same time.
]
***Reason that made me ask this question:***
Because if temperature depends upon the KE of molecules and we oscillate the pressure we will just be shaking the molecules inside. So this should increase the temperature as well because the more you shake the more motion particles do.

***Statement:*** *[I know temperature is directly proportional to Pressure but is it also proportional to "*the rate of oscillation*" of pressure?]*

Comment: Your example is inconsistent with the preceding statement as it involves oscillation of temperature, not pressure. Please clarify.

Comment: Considerably at which frequency?

Comment: It depends, are you increasing the pressure slow enough so that pressure is well defined and the same at all points inside the box, are you allowing for pressure waves, or turbulence? are you allowing heat exchange with the surroundings? etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify things, let the gas exhibit ideal gas behavior for the range in temperatures and pressures involved. Then we can apply the ideal gas equation of state and general gas equation for equilibrium:

$$PV=nRT$$

$$\frac{P_{1}V_{1}}{T_{1}}=\frac{P_{2}V_{2}}{T_{2}}$$

> From oscillation of pressure I mean constantly increasing and
> decreasing the pressure by a fixed amount. For example imagine a room
> with a pressure of 50 pascal, if we first increase its temperature to
> 55 and then decrease the temperature to 45 that would be oscillating
> the temperature by 5 units back and forth

Your example is inconsistent with the preceding statement as it involves oscillation of temperature, not pressure. In any event, oscillations in pressure can create viscous friction in gases that, in turn, can increase the internal energy and temperature. This is the result of the generation of entropy in an irreversible (non-quasistatic) process.

> Statement: [I know temperature is directly proportional to Pressure
> but is it also proportional to "the rate of oscillation" of pressure?]

For an ideal gas, temperature is directly proportional to pressure only under equilibrium conditions for a closed system where the volume is constant.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you increase the pressure it means that or you reduce the volume of the container  or you added more molecules on the system, this means that will be more number of collisions between this molecules because there are less space between them so the temperature will rise up. When you add more volume the space between molecules will be greater so there will be less collisions decreasing the temperature. The only way to "shake" the molecules is making a variable magnetic field that goes through the molecules increasing their potential energy and rotating them increasing the heat (This only work for polar molecules).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases